Python Version Mismatch in Jupyter Notebook Environment
I am experiencing a discrepancy between the Python version reported in the Jupyter notebook startup banner and the version shown when I query python --version within the notebook. The startup banner indicates Python 3.11.9, but when I run !python --version, it returns Python 3.11.7.
Steps I did:

base conda has 3.11.7 version
conda create --prefix ~/.conda/pypypy python=3.11.9
conda activate ~/.conda/pypypy
python -m ipykernel install --user --name pypypy

Expected Behavior:
The Python version queried within the notebook should match the version indicated in the startup banner. But in reality there is a mismatch:

Troubleshooting Done:

Checked the environment's kernel specification file (kernel.json) to ensure it points to the correct Python executable.

(/home/karzymatov/.conda/pypypy) karzymatov@55f26f77b14d:~/mtb_join$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python3    /home/karzymatov/.conda/pypypy/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
  pypypy     /home/karzymatov/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/pypypy

cat /home/karzymatov/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/pypypy/kernel.json 
{
 "argv": [
  "/home/karzymatov/.conda/pypypy/bin/python",
  "-Xfrozen_modules=off",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "pypypy",
 "language": "python",
 "metadata": {
  "debugger": true
 }



Ensured that the notebook is using the intended kernel.

Could someone help explain why this discrepancy occurs and how to ensure that the notebook uses the correct Python version as indicated in the startup banner?

Why do you expect !python to consult your notebook's settings? It simply runs a shell command, subject to your regular PATH

@tripleee so it might already had worked OK?

If the virtual environment was active in the terminal where you started your notebook, yes; but I imagine you probably started it with some GUI clicks.

One solution is
conda install -c conda-forge nb_conda_kernels

and restart the server
